# Getting : Correct classpath for reactor.netty.resources.ConnectionProvider$Builder while running spring project

Tags: java, spring-boot, netty

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

```
org.springframework.cloud.gateway.config.GatewayAutoConfiguration$NettyConfiguration.buildConnectionProvider(GatewayAutoConfiguration.java:798)
```

The following method did not exist:

```
reactor.netty.resources.ConnectionProvider$Builder.evictInBackground(Ljava/time/Duration;)Lreactor/netty/resources/ConnectionProvider$ConnectionPoolSpec;
```

The method's class, reactor.netty.resources.ConnectionProvider$Builder, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/Sam/.m2/repository/io/projectreactor/netty/reactor-netty/0.9.12.RELEASE/reactor-netty-0.9.12.RELEASE.jar!/reactor/netty/resources/ConnectionProvider$Builder.class
```

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

```
reactor.netty.resources.ConnectionProvider.Builder: file:/C:/Users/Sam/.m2/repository/io/projectreactor/netty/reactor-netty/0.9.12.RELEASE/reactor-netty-0.9.12.RELEASE.jar
reactor.netty.resources.ConnectionProvider.ConnectionPoolSpec: file:/C:/Users/Sam/.m2/repository/io/projectreactor/netty/reactor-netty/0.9.12.RELEASE/reactor-netty-0.9.12.RELEASE.jar
```

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of reactor.netty.resources.ConnectionProvider$Builder

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: The version of Spring Cloud Gateway that you are using is incompatible with the version of Reactor Netty that you are using. Can you share your build.gradle or pom.xml file so that we can see where the versions are coming from?

Comment: Hey man,
Sorry for the late response.
This is my pom for the project : https://github.com/sam112358/cloud-gateway/blob/main/pom.xml
TIA

Answer (score 1):

The method's that missing is [new in Reactor Netty 0.9.13.RELEASE](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/commit/f4fa30b6fb89707864119dffdf83309ba42165e7) and you're using 0.9.12.RELEASE at the moment. This version is coming from Spring Boot 2.3.4's dependency management. Spring Boot 2.3.5 upgraded to Reactor Netty 0.9.13.RELEASE so you can fix the problem by upgrading to Spring Boot 2.3.5 or later.

Given that you're using Spring Cloud Hoxton.SR11 which was released in April 2021, I would recommend upgrading to a similarly recent Spring Boot 2.3.x release. 2.3.11.RELEASE is the latest available release at the time of writing.